# Assign argument to variables in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a code to send and receive files between two client and server but I want both functions in one program. So I wrote a separate class containing send and receive functions. I have declared two variables `sendFilePath` and `receiveFilePath`. I called the method 
`transfer(String sendFileName, String receiveFileName)` and assigned values to these variables but it is showing null.

How can I do this?

Actually I want to send `sendFilePath` to `rf.receive();` and `receiveFilePath` to `sf.send();` method how it can be done?

```
class TransferFile implements Runnable
{    
    Thread thread;

    String sendFilePath, receiveFilePath;
    SendFile sf = new SendFile();
    ReceiveFile rf = new ReceiveFile();

    public void TransferFileCreateThread(String name)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this,name);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        rf.receive(sendFilePath);
        sf.send(receiveFilePath);
    }

    public void transfer(String sendFileName, String receiveFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            sendFilePath = sendFileName;
            receiveFilePath = receiveFileName;

            TransferFile t1 = new TransferFile();
            TransferFile t2 = new TransferFile();
            t1.TransferFileCreateThread(sendFilePath);
            t2.TransferFileCreateThread(receiveFilePath);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking, please clarify it with snippet of usage of your class and comments what is null and where

Comment: What is the problem exactly... The questions seems to be either incomplete or you are assuming that the one reading it would know your situation. Please elaborate on the same.

Comment: i assigned sendFilePath = sendFileName;
            receiveFilePath = receiveFileName; values in transfer method but in run method the values of sendFilePath and receiveFilePath are null. why it is showing null?

Comment: I'm a little baffled: You're trying to send/recieve files but what you transfer is paths?

Comment: code looks incomplete, or not matching the question. You say you want "to send sendFilePath to rf.receive();" but this is what you do when you pass it as argument, right?

Answer (score 0):

here you are creating new object t1 and t2,
you are not assigning values to objects t1 and t2.

you can do this in this way..

```
class TransferFile implements Runnable
{    
    Thread thread;

    private String sendFilePath=null;
    private String receiveFilePath=null;
    SendFile sf = new SendFile();
    ReceiveFile rf = new ReceiveFile();

    public void TransferFileCreateThread(String name)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this,name);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        rf.receive(sendFilePath);
        sf.send(receiveFilePath);
    }
    public void setSendFilePath(String filePath){
         this.sendFilePath=filePath;
    }
    public void setReceiveFilePath(String filePath){
         this.receiveFilePath=filePath;
    }
    public void transfer(String sendFileName, String receiveFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            sendFilePath = sendFileName;
            receiveFilePath = receiveFileName;

            TransferFile t1 = new TransferFile();
            t1.setSendFilePath(sendFilePath);
            t1.setReceiverFilePath(receiveFilePath);
            TransferFile t2 = new TransferFile();
            t1.setSendFilePath(sendFilePath);
            t1.setReceiverFilePath(receiveFilePath);
            t1.TransferFileCreateThread(sendFilePath);
            t2.TransferFileCreateThread(receiveFilePath);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps..

what another thing you can do is you can call tranfer method on t1 and t2 so it will asign values to string objects.